# php laravel Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm just beginning to learn how to use Laravel and I'm running into a problem with returning multiple variables.

In my controller I have it set up as:

```
return view('pages.about')->withFullName($fullname)->withEmail($email);
```

Then in my view I have:

```
<p>Email me at {{$email}}</p>
```

The $fullname variable passes without any problem but when I have the additional variable $email in there it's giving me a parse error.

Comment: have you checked by {{dd(email)}} OR {{dump($email)}}

Comment: You are using Laravel 'magic methods', I have tested your code and there is no reason it should not work. It is likely that you have an extra parentheses or something in your view causing the error.

Comment: Share more code?

Comment: @user2963379, please mark the correct answer (by clicking the checkbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways to pass variable to views. You can try it using below mentioned ways -

1. `$data['fullname'] = $fullname; $data['email'] = $email;` Then `return view('pages.about', $data);`
2. Another way can be using compact like this `return view('pages.about', compact('fullname', 'email'))`
3. If you want to use your current approach, then  change it to `return view('pages.about')->with(compact('fullname'))->with(compact('email'));`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a fancier, newer syntax, and it's possible that there's a bug.

Try this:

```
return view('pages.about')->with('fullName', $fullname)->with('email', $email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your code... if the error is showing this line where you return the view it's likely that the line before it hasn't got a semicolon at the end. The chained dynamic `with*` shouldn't be causing any issues.